# Python/Numpy equivalent of MATLAB isosurface functions

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, isosurface

Anyone can suggest the equivalent function of MATLAB's "isosurface" function in python/numpy. The MATLAB isosurface returns the faces and vertices. I need the faces and vertices to create .stl files. MATLAB isosurface function looks like this:

```
[f,v] = isosurface(X,Y,Z,V,isovalue)
```

in python I have found this one method in plotly which works as follows:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

X, Y, Z = np.mgrid[-5:5:40j, -5:5:40j, -5:5:40j]

# ellipsoid
values = X * X * 0.5 + Y * Y + Z * Z * 2

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Isosurface(
    x=X.flatten(),
    y=Y.flatten(),
    z=Z.flatten(),
    value=values.flatten(),
    isomin=10,
    isomax=40,
    caps=dict(x_show=False, y_show=False)
    ))
fig.show()
```

the problem with this method is that it only plots isosurfaces and doesn't return faces and vertices as the MATLAB isosurface function does and I need those faces and vertices.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think numpy or scipy easily support this. If you're open to more esoteric solutions, [pyvista](https://docs.pyvista.org/index.html) based on VTK can do this easily. 1. Create a mesh from your data, 2. use `surfaces = mesh.contour(isovalues)` to contour it, and 3.  `surfaces.save('output.stl')` should save the whole mesh, complete with faces and vertices.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you please elaborate on how to create the mesh?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although it wasn't among your target libraries, [PyVista](https://docs.pyvista.org/) built on VTK can help you do this easily (disclaimer: I'm one of the devs). Since you seemed receptive of a PyVista-based solution in comments, here's how you'd do it:

1. define a mesh, generally as a [`StructuredGrid`](https://docs.pyvista.org/examples/00-load/create-structured-surface.html) for your kind of data, although the equidistant grid in your example could even work with a [`UniformGrid`](https://docs.pyvista.org/examples/00-load/create-uniform-grid.html),
2. compute its isosurfaces with a [`contour`](https://docs.pyvista.org/examples/01-filter/contouring.html#sphx-glr-examples-01-filter-contouring-py) filter,
3. save as an `.stl` file using the [`save`](https://docs.pyvista.org/core/points.html#pyvista.PolyData.save) method of the grid containing the isosurfaces.

```py
import numpy as np
import pyvista as pv

# generate data grid for computing the values
X, Y, Z = np.mgrid[-5:5:40j, -5:5:40j, -5:5:40j]
values = X**2 * 0.5 + Y**2 + Z**2 * 2

# create a structured grid
# (for this simple example we could've used an unstructured grid too)
# note the fortran-order call to ravel()!
mesh = pv.StructuredGrid(X, Y, Z)
mesh.point_arrays['values'] = values.ravel(order='F')  # also the active scalars

# compute 3 isosurfaces
isos = mesh.contour(isosurfaces=3, rng=[10, 40])
# or: mesh.contour(isosurfaces=np.linspace(10, 40, 3)) etc.

# plot them interactively if you want to
isos.plot(opacity=0.7)

# save to stl
isos.save('isosurfaces.stl')
```

The interactive plot looks something like this:
[image: 3d plot of three ellipsoidal isosurfaces with partial opacity, coloured according to iso values]

The colours correspond to the isovalues, picked from the scalars array and indicated by the scalar bar.

If we load back the mesh from file we'll get the structure, but not the scalars:

```py
loaded = pv.read('isosurfaces.stl')
loaded.plot(opacity=0.7)
```

[image: same figure when loaded back from .stl file, but everything is white and there is no scalar bar]

The reason why the scalars are missing is that data arrays can't be exported to `.stl` files:

```py
>>> isos  # original isosurface mesh
PolyData (0x7fa7245a2220)
  N Cells:  26664
  N Points: 13656
  X Bounds: -4.470e+00, 4.470e+00
  Y Bounds: -5.000e+00, 5.000e+00
  Z Bounds: -5.000e+00, 5.000e+00
  N Arrays: 3

>>> isos.point_arrays
pyvista DataSetAttributes
Association: POINT
Contains keys:
    values
    Normals

>>> isos.cell_arrays
pyvista DataSetAttributes
Association: CELL
Contains keys:
    Normals

>>> loaded  # read back from .stl file
PolyData (0x7fa7118e7d00)
  N Cells:  26664
  N Points: 13656
  X Bounds: -4.470e+00, 4.470e+00
  Y Bounds: -5.000e+00, 5.000e+00
  Z Bounds: -5.000e+00, 5.000e+00
  N Arrays: 0
```

While the original isosurfaces each had the isovalues bound to them (providing the colour mapping seen in the first figure), as well as point and cell normals (computed by the call to `.save()` for some reason), there's no data in the latter case.

Still, since you're looking for vertices and faces, this should do just fine. In case you need it, you can also access these on the PyVista side, since the isosurface mesh is a `PolyData` object:

```py
>>> isos.n_points, isos.n_cells
(13656, 26664)

>>> isos.points.shape  # each row is a point
(13656, 3)

>>> isos.faces
array([    3,     0,    45, ..., 13529, 13531, 13530])

>>> isos.faces.shape
(106656,)
```

Now the logistics of the faces is a bit tricky. They are all encoded in a 1d array of integers. In the 1d array you always have an integer `n` telling you the size of the given face, and then `n` zero-based indices corresponding to points in the points array. The above isosurfaces consist entirely of triangles:

```py
>>> isos.faces[::4]  # [3 i1 i2 i3] quadruples encode faces
array([3, 3, 3, ..., 3, 3, 3])

>>> isos.is_all_triangles()
True
```

Which is why you'll see

```
>>> isos.faces.size == 4 * isos.n_cells
True
```

and you could do `isos.faces.reshape(-1, 4)` to get a 2d array where each row corresponds to a triangular face (and the first column is constant 3).

Comment: Does PyVista also support 3d Numpy arrays with a Uniform Grid? I am investigating how to get the marching cube method to work with a 3D Numpy array. The examples at https://docs.pyvista.org/examples/01-filter/flying_edges.html all show how to create a Uniform Grid for a specific function.

Comment: @Axion004 yup. Something like this should work: `grid = pv.UniformGrid(dimensions=arr.shape); grid.point_data['scalars'] = arr.ravel(); grid.plot()`. (I _think_ you don't need `arr.ravel('F')`.) The linked example actually does the same thing, but instead of assigning the `values` scalars to the grid it just passes that array directly to `grid.contour()`. But you could assign the same scalars array to the points like I just showed.

Answer (score 0):

There's no equivalent function of MATLAB's "isosurface" function in python/numpy. You need Marching Cube from Scikit-image to return faces and vertices.

https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html?highlight=marching%20cube#skimage.measure.marching_cubes

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33130963)

Answer (score 0):

The [marching_cubes](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.marching_cubes) method from [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/) provides vertices of triangles on the iso-surface. However, the vertices are in terms of indices of the 3D function. To convert from indices to actual coordinates, we can use the [interp](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) method for 1D interpolation by [Numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/index.html). Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.measure import marching_cubes

...

x_coordinates = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
y_coordinates = np.linspace(0, 1, 20)
z_coordinates = np.linspace(0, 1, 30)

...

def getLocationOnAxis(vertices:np.ndarray, axis:np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray :

    return np.interp(vertices, np.arange(axis.shape[0]), axis)

# Note func_3D_values must be a 3D array
# with cartesian indexing, i.e.,
# func_3D_values.shape = (10, 20, 30)
vertices, faces, normals, values = marching_cubes(func_3D_values, level)

vertices_x = getLocationOnAxis(vertices[:, 0], x_coordinates)
vertices_y = getLocationOnAxis(vertices[:, 1], y_coordinates)
vertices_z = getLocationOnAxis(vertices[:, 2], z_coordinates)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

ax.plot_trisurf(vertices_x, vertices_y, vertices_z, triangles=faces)
```

This example can be modified to work on any rectilinear 3D grid.